# Passing parameters to BroadcastReceiver subclass - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Pass additional parameters to a dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver.

The problem is basic: I want to pass parameters to a BroadcastReceiver. Can this be done? Even when the receiver is created dynamically?

Additionally, say I create an anonymous BroadcastReceiver i.e. as a variable implementation. Can I reference the encapsulating class variables? Check the code below for how I stop / start the file observer.

```
        // Create the external media broadcast receiver.
        mExternalMediaBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
                // if action = media removed, stop the file observer.
                EncapsulatingFragment.this.mFileObserver.stopWatching()
            }
        };
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this valid?

So long as the receiver has the same lifetime as `EncapsulatingFragment.this`, probably.

> I want to pass parameters to a BroadcastReceiver. Can this be done? Even when the receiver is created dynamically?

Create an actual class and pass in the values to the constructor:

```
class WhateverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  FileObserver mFileObserver;

  WhateverReceiver(FileObserver observer) {
    mFileObserver = observer;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    // if action = media removed, stop the file observer.
    mFileObserver.stopWatching();
  }
}
```

Then, in your fragment:

```
mExternalMediaBroadcastReceiver = new WhateverReceiver(mFileObserver);
```

All that being said... you might want to consider whether this logic should be implemented in your fragment. I/O-related stuff ideally lies outside of a fragment, such as in a repository object.

Comment: Yeah, I have a separate class for processing all of the logic and receiving all events from the observed directory. Additionally, I don't have to create a new instance of the receiver each time, correct? Create the instance once, and register / unregister it on resume and pause, correct? This should ensure the same life-time.

Comment: @Dan: "I have a separate class for processing all of the logic and receiving all events from the observed directory" -- if that is a repository-style singleton, I would have it have the `FileObserver` and the `BroadcastReceiver`, and get all of this out of the fragment. "Create the instance once, and register / unregister it on resume and pause, correct?" -- that should be fine.

Comment: The FileObserver implementation class is not a singleton, however, it abides by the fragments lifecycle i.e. I start and stop it on resume and pause, respectively. Additionally, the FileObserver makes use of WeakReferences. Is that still alright?